# using "apply()" with methods that return void in specman

Tags: list, specman

Specman has the `apply()` method to perform the same action on all elements of a list:

```
var a: list of int;
a = somefunction.that.returns.list.of.int();
var b:= a.apply(it * 2);
```

Where `apply()` does the same as:

```
for each in a {
    b.add(it.*2);
};
```

Now, if I want to call a method on the elements of `a`, I can use `apply()` so long as the method returns a value.  However, if I have:

```
struct bar {
    x: int;

    foo() is {
       message(LOW, "x is ", x); 
    };
};
```

And I try to do:

```
var a: list of bar;
a = somefunction.that.returns.list.of.bar();
a.apply(it.foo());
```

It doesn't compile, because `foo()` returns `void`.  Instead, I have to use an explicit loop:

```
for each in a {
    it.foo();
};
```

Is there a method in specman similar to `apply()` that doesn't require a return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic problem here is that you want to mis-use `apply()`. I would say this function has some *functional programming* background and its purpose is to do something which each item of a list and return a *new* list (like `map` in Python or Perl).

If you are interested in the *side-effects* of a function call, which you are if the function doesn't return a value, its more correct to use the explicit loop. See also [Is there a value in using map() vs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875337/is-there-a-value-in-using-map-vs-for)

This said I can't think of a different solution at the moment. Maybe wrapping `foo()` in a value-returning function but this definitely seems overload.